# What causes a 'Type expected' error in JSP?

Tags: jsp

In a JSP file I'm getting a:

```
Type expected (found 'try' instead)
```

Error while attempting to set up a connection.  This leaves me with two questions.  What is going wrong here?  and more generally, what causes 'Type Expected' Errors in JSP? Since I can't find an explanation of the error in a Google search.  Here's the code.

```
<%!
class ThisPage extends ModernPage
{
     try{
        Connection con=null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
        con = HomeInterfaceHelper.getInstance().getConnection();
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("sql goes here");
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        con.close();  
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("sql error: exception thrown");
    }
}
%>
```

Edited to show more code

Comment: Sounds like you have a syntax error somewhere; could you paste in the few lines before the `try`?

Comment: Sounds like a missing ';' to me on the line before try...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Zoogie.  But other that the includes, this is the entire file.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: In case anyone was wondering about the literal answer to the title of "What causes a type expected error?" I found this:
http://mindprod.com/jgloss/compileerrormessages.html#TYPEEXPECTED

Comment: I just want to let know that this is not the best approach to do DB stuff. 1) This code belongs in a real Java class, not in a JSP file. 2) closing resources (all three!) should be done in a `finally`. Also see [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you can't add a `try .. catch` block inside a class declaration, you should at least put it inside a method like the constructor of the class or a `static { }` block.

I don't know if JSP's syntax is different but did you try something like:

```
class ThisPage extends ModernPage {
  Connection con;
  PreparedStatement pstmt;


  ThisPage() {
    try{
      con=null;
      pstmt=null;
      con = HomeInterfaceHelper.getInstance().getConnection();
      pstmt = con.prepareStatement("sql goes here");
      ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
      con.close();  
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("sql error: exception thrown");
    }
  }
}
```

If you look at [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/first_edition/html/19.doc.html) you can see that a **TryStatement** cannot be inserted inside a class declaration..

Comment: An alternative to this, is an initialization block. Just another `{` and `}` surrounding the `try-catch` block.